# Access is denied while executing aspnet_regbrowsers.exe

Tags: asp.net-3.5

For one of our requirement, we had to modify the ie.browser and web.config files (%windir%\microsoft.Net\Framework64\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\Browsers and %windir%\microsoft.Net\Framework64\v2.0.50727\CONFIG). After modifying these files, when I execute aspnet_regbrowsers.exe, we are getting access denied error. Following is the error message:

```
ASPRUNTIME: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005(E_ACCESSDENIED))
```

I have executed aspnet_regbrowsers.exe (available at %windir%\microsoft.Net\Framework64\v2.0.50727) from command prompt under administrative privileges. I am facing this on windows server 2008 R2 x64 bit.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi kiran kumar, I know this question was a looong time ago, but I just encountered this bizarre behavior, and wondered if you remember finding a solution for this Access Denied error?